# Matlab matrix: Get a cell array of strings of the header for values in each row

Tags: excel, vba

I get a raw matrix from a Excel-File like this:

[image]

with this code:

```
% Read Excel File
filename = 'Name_of_Excel_File.xlsx';

% Set Sheet and Size
% If you want to try, use the correct sheet number
Sheet = 3; 
Impact = 'A1:H7';

% Read and save to matrix
[~,~,Impact] = xlsread(filename,Sheet,Impact);
```

I get this raw impact matrix:

[image]

Now comes the tricky part and I don't know how to start my problem solving process.

I´d like to get a seperate string cell array for each row.
For example

```
One = 'A'    'C'    'D'    'F'
```

and

```
Two = 'B'    'G'
```

and so on.

I´d like to get for each row a cell array of strings. The strings should be the ones in the header for the numbers in their column.

Which possibilities do I have for this problem?

Comment: So what did you try to collect this info? Note that some research on the subject is required by Stack Overflow policy, see [ask]. For starters: get a matrix of the numbers (meaning of `matrix(2:end,2:end)`, and use `isnan` to extract the numbers. Also is is unclear how different numbers act; in the sense that `one C` is `3`, but appears only once. Please [edit] the question with more details and what you already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me, what should be your output? I get that you want to store the column names for each numerical values for respctive rows in an array, but it's not clear to me, once you actually save the data in the array what should we do with it. Display it in a row? Something else..? Or are you only interested in the algorhytm for filling the array with string values?

Comment: Yes I created a minimum example of my problem and I´m only interested in the algorithm to store the values for each numerical values for respective rows in a column array. I edited my questions just with numerical values by "1".  The different numbers are interesting for another function.

Comment: One more question. Do your arrays have to absolutely be called `'One'` `'Two'`etc? Could it perhaps be for example `'array1'` `'array2'` and so on? I'm asking, because it's generally a bad practice to use `.toString()` method for variable names. Would be much easier if we used a static variable name with increasing index series

Comment: The strings in the first column have specific names in several sheets. For example I have six sheets and each one of them has in the second row the string 'technology' and in the third row 'process'. For a good overview of this, it would be nice to have these specific strings as an array tag. Does this answer your question?

Comment: OK, 'array1', 'array2' or something like that would be ok as well for a start. I just don't know how to start because I tried 'find' and 'nan' is not working for a raw matrix.